# ScriptBundle with additional attributes

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, web-optimization, scriptbundle

```
public class BundleConfig
{
    // For more information on Bundling, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=254725
    public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/require").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/require.js"));
       ....
```

and in the _Layout.cshtml

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/require")
```

it renders into (with `EnableOptimizations = false`):

```
<script src="/Scripts/require.js"></script>
```

but I want to add an attribute

```
<script src="/Scripts/require.js" data-main="/Scripts/main"></script>
```

how could I do that?

Comment: I heard some MVC's alpha update adds RenderFormat method, but I'd rather find another way, if there's any

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've solved similar issue by configuring requirejs without data-main attribute. So, at first I had following code:

```
<script src="app/rconfig.js"></script>
<script src="plugin/requirejs/require.js" data-main="app/main.js"></script>
```

Next, let's get rid from the data-main attribute:

```
<script src="app/rconfig.js"></script>
<script src="plugin/requirejs/require.js"></script>
<script>
    require.config({
        baseUrl: "app"
    });
    require(['app/main.js']);
</script>
```

Next, I've put last 'script' content to the file:

```
<script src="app/rconfig.js"></script>
<script src="plugin/requirejs/require.js"></script>
<script src="app/rdatamain.js"></script>
```

At finish, I've put these three files to the bundle

Answer (score 1):

If you don't like RenderFormat, you can change the DefaultTagFormat globally on the ScriptsHelper too, but this attribute would now show up everywhere you called Scripts.Render